# Eclipse plugin - is there any editable TreeSelection class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a solution to make this tree selection editable in the package explorer view itself.

the idea

for example- if we click rename on any class in package explorer, it will prompt a new window to rename. This functionality is same for any class that implement TreeSelection Class.

But the Solution i am looking for is -  when rename is invoked, the rename option is shown at the tree itself (like we have in Windows Explorer view)

any suggestion on how to attain this behavior on eclipse.

[image: Tree selection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have some special editable selection, you just want to make the tree editable. For this you use `EditingSupport`, like this (adapted from http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_editor):

```
public class NameEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {
  private final TreeViewer viewer;

  public FirstNameEditingSupport(TreeViewer viewer) {
    super(viewer);
    this.viewer = viewer;
  }

  @Override
  protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
    return new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTree());
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object getValue(Object element) {
    // return the name
  }

  @Override
  protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
    // update the name of your object
    viewer.update(element, null);
  }
} 

// in the code creating the tree
treeViewer.setEditingSupport(new NameEditingSupport(treeViewer));
```